# About auto layouts

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, autolayout

As I have given auto layout for the collection view but in portrait it was fine:

[image: as I have given auto layout for the collection view but in portrait it was fine]

The problem is that where as coming to landscape the gap between the cells are increasing. How to avoid this?

[image: the problem is that where as coming to landscape the gap between the cells are increasing how to avoid this ?]

---

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var images = ["apple","banana","cherry","grapes","kiwifruit","mangoes","orange","papaya","passionfruit","peaches","pineapple","strawberry","sugarapple","watermelon"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(orientationChanged(notification:)), name: Notification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self

    }
    func orientationChanged(notification: Notification) {
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
        func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return images.count
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "stridentifier",for:indexPath) as! FruitsCollectionViewCell


            cell.image.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])
            cell.nameLabel.text = images[indexPath.row]

            return cell
        }
    class SampleCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        override init() {
            super.init()
            setUpLayout()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            setUpLayout()
        }

        override var itemSize: CGSize {
            set {}
            get {
                let itemWidth = ((self.collectionView?.bounds.width)! / 3.0) - self.minimumLineSpacing - minimumInteritemSpacing
                return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
            }
        }

        func setUpLayout() {
            minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
            minimumLineSpacing = 1.0
            scrollDirection = .vertical
        }

        override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
            return true 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using UICollectionViewFlowLayout or you have subclassed it?

Comment: Have you fix Cell size in CollectionView ?

Comment: no I have not used uicollectionviewflowlayout

Comment: Please explain your question in details, what have you tried, what is this? UITableVIew, UICollectionView, UIScrollView?. Add code in question if you wrote any for Auto layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though i am bit late in this thread.But my solution will work in every devices according to your specification. 2 cells in portrait and 3 cells in landscape.But you can increase cell number according to your choice just modify **NUMBER_OF_CELLS_IN_PORTRAIT**   and **NUMBER_OF_CELLS_IN_LANDSCAPE**

I have made comment in every function.So it may be understandable.

At first i made some default value .

```
let SCREEN_WIDTH = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
let SCREEN_HEIGHT = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

let BASE_SCREEN_HEIGHT:CGFloat = 736.0
let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH = max(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
let ASPECT_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_7P = SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH / BASE_SCREEN_HEIGHT

let MINIMUM_INTERITEM_SPACING:CGFloat = 14.0 //My Default Inter Cell Spacing for iphone 7plus as i have designed in it.
var ITEM_WIDTH:CGFloat  = 200 //for iPhone 7 plus.initial value
var ITEM_HEIGHT:CGFloat = 200 //for iphone 7 plus.initial value
let NUMBER_OF_CELLS_IN_PORTRAIT:CGFloat = 2
let NUMBER_OF_CELLS_IN_LANDSCAPE:CGFloat = 3
```

Then in viewDidLoad i initialize the collection view with the following function

```
func initialCollectionData() {
    let orientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
    if orientation == .portrait {
        self.calculateCellSize(screenWidth:SCREEN_WIDTH ,cellItem: NUMBER_OF_CELLS_IN_PORTRAIT)
    }
    else {
        self.calculateCellSize(screenWidth:SCREEN_WIDTH ,cellItem: NUMBER_OF_CELLS_IN_LANDSCAPE)
    }
}
```

And there are some helper function. Like this.

```
//This method calculate cellsize according to cell number.
func  calculateCellSize(screenWidth:CGFloat , cellItem:CGFloat) {
    ITEM_WIDTH = (screenWidth - MINIMUM_INTERITEM_SPACING * ASPECT_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_7P  * (cellItem-1)) / cellItem  - 1// This 1 has been subtracted from ITEM_WIDTH to remove mantissa
    ITEM_HEIGHT = ITEM_WIDTH
}

//This method calculate cell number according to orientation.
func findCellItem(screenWidth:CGFloat)  {
    let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
    if orientation == .portrait {
        self.calculateCellSize(screenWidth:screenWidth ,cellItem: NUMBER_OF_CELLS_IN_PORTRAIT) //You have chosen 2 cells to show in portrait
    }
    else {
        self.calculateCellSize(screenWidth:screenWidth ,cellItem: NUMBER_OF_CELLS_IN_LANDSCAPE) ////You have chosen 3 cells to show in portrait
    }
}

//During orientation change this method is called everytime.
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in

        context.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)
        //Below two methods do the trick
        self.findCellItem(screenWidth: size.width)
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }, completion: {
        _ in
    })

}
```

//Collection View delegate methods

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let collectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    collectionCell.fruitImage.image = UIImage.init(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])
    return collectionCell


}


 public func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize.init(width: ITEM_WIDTH , height: ITEM_HEIGHT )
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
   return MINIMUM_INTERITEM_SPACING * ASPECT_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_7P
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return MINIMUM_INTERITEM_SPACING * ASPECT_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_7P
}
```

Comment: but let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH = max(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
        let ASPECT_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_7 = SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH / BASE_SCREEN_HEIGHT code should not be there if it is there we will get an error an later I put that code in func  calculateCellSize then no error and worked perfectly

Comment: did you call self. initialCollectionData() function in viewDidLoad?

Comment: now I have done that I got it but the space between two columns is increasing in landscape mode what should I do know ?

Comment: Dude, i checked and double checked in all devices and it's working fine in both mode.

Comment: but line spacing was more in landscape how to reduce this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have subclassed UICollectionViewFlowLayout you need to override `itemSize` and setup `minimumInteritemSpacing`, `minimumLineSpacing` once you have done that when the orientation changes you need to tell the collection view to reset the layout using 
`collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()`

If you haven't subclassed it you need to override

`collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize`

Whenever the device rotates call the 
`collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()`

You will have to add notification for device rotation.

Here is a sample UICollectionViewFlowLayout for 3 columns

```
class SampleCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        setUpLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setUpLayout()
    }

    override var itemSize: CGSize {
        set {}
        get {
             // 2 columns in portrait and 3 in landscape
          if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isPortrait {
           let itemWidth = ((self.collectionView?.bounds.width)! / 2.0) - self.minimumLineSpacing - minimumInteritemSpacing
           return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
         }
          let itemWidth = ((self.collectionView?.bounds.width)! / 3.0) - self.minimumLineSpacing - minimumInteritemSpacing
            return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
        }
    }

    func setUpLayout() {
        minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        minimumLineSpacing = 1.0
        scrollDirection = .vertical
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true 
    }
}
```

Add this line in `viewDidLoad`

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(orientationChanged(notification:)), name: Notification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
```

and add the function

```
func orientationChanged(notification: Notification) {
  collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Also if you are using customLayout you need to go to the xib->select the collectionView->attributes inspector(4th option)-> Tap Layout and select Custom and put the name of the subclassed UICollectionViewLayout class(SampleCollectionViewFlowLayout) in our case.

You need to set UICollectionViewFlowLayout class here after selecting the UICollectionView in you Storyboard/xib file

[image]

Comment: how to add notification can u please tell me clearly i was new to swift

Comment: did you add the orientation method and can you confirm its working?

Comment: It seems you have added the UICollectionViewFlowLayout class within the controller. I have my sample on github check this [link](https://github.com/rameeznkhan/SampleCollectionViewFlowLayout)

Comment: I tried by using you code but it did not work may be because of label I think too

Comment: My code works i have tested it. Make a new file for UICollectionViewLayout and make sure you are setting it in the xib

Comment: We need to check you code then. Have you added a different file for UICollectionViewFlowLayout, once you have done that post the code only for you viewcontroller we will check that.

Comment: your code also working fine in landscape but in portrait I need two images in a row to fit the screen

Comment: i changed the code for itemSize please check. If this solutions works for you please accept the answer :)

Comment: if I change there it is affecting both portrait and landscape

Comment: edited my answer it will display 2 columns in portrait and 3 in landscape. Please check and let me know if that works

Answer (score -1):

Just add the following lines in your ViewController :

```
override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    self.yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

And set proper size in this delegate method :

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
```

Comment: I down-voted this answer because it is posted in 2017 where the method `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` has already been depricated by Apple.